# Need help deriving regression statistics

Tags: regression, self-study

I am self-studying [this book](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/) and need assistance on one of the exercises, specifically 3.9.2:

Suppose that, for a certain population, we can predict log earnings from log height as follows:

- A person who is 66 inches tall is predicted to have earnings of $30K.
- Every increase of 1% in height corresponds to a predicted increase of 0.8% in earnings.
- The earnings of approximately 95% of people fall within a factor of 1.1 of predicted values.

(a)  Give the equation of the regression line and the residual standard deviation of the regression.

For this part, I use the first and second bullets to get the equation $\ln(30,000) = .008\ln(66) + c$ and, solving for $c$, I get the regression equation $\ln(earnings) = .008 \ln(height) + 10.257$.  Is this correct?

For the second part of the question, I need help determining how to find the residual standard deviation of the regression.  If $p$ is the value of the prediction line in the residual plot, then it follows that $p \pm 2\sigma = p \pm 1.1p$, based on the third bullet.  However, I'm not sure how to actually calculate $\sigma$.

(b)  Suppose the standard deviation of log heights is 5% in this population.  What then, is the $R^2$ of the regression model described here?

No idea where to start on this one...could I get a hint, please?

Comment: (1) You're doing well, but think about how to interpret the percents in the second bullet. Drawing a picture (on log-log axes) will help you compare 0.8% to 1%. (2) In the third bullet, remember you need to work with *logarithms*. Thus, "within a factor of 1.1" means "give or take $\log(1.1)$". This will enable you to answer the second half of question (a). (3) To obtain $R^2$, use your answer to the second half of (a) along with the new information in question (b).